# How do I get the byte values of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, ascii, bytecode

Say I have a string in php, that prints out to a text file like this:

nÖ§9q1Fª£

How do I get the byte codes of this to my text file rather than the funky ascii characters?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the ord function

http://ca.php.net/ord

eg.

```
<?php
$var = "nÖ§9q1Fª£ˆæÓ§Œ_»—Ló]j";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($var); $i++)
{
   echo ord($var[$i])."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: @YzmirRamirez: to show bytes you need byte length, not character length, so using `mb_strlen` is actually bug.

Comment: You are correct @Ped7g.  I generally use the mb_ functions and saw strlen call above.  But the better answer is below that doesn't require for loops.

Answer (score 24):

If You wish to get the string as an array of integer codes, there's a nice one-liner:

```
unpack('C*', $string)
```

Beware, the resulting array is indexed from 1, not from 0!

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about the hex value, this should do for you:

```
$value = unpack('H*', "Stack");
echo $value[1];
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382738/convert-string-to-binary-then-back-again-using-php)

Comment: This is a great answer; much better than fiddling with `for` loops and individual characters.

Answer (score 2):

[`Ord()`](http://php.net/ord) does the trick with an ASCII-charset. If you, however, meddle with multibyte strings (like UTF-8), you're out of luck, and need to hack it yourself.