# What is the php equivalent for Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vstrEncryptionKey.ToCharArray())

Tags: c#, php

What is the PHP equivalent for  the following C# code

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vstrEncryptionKey.ToCharArray())
```

where `vstrEncryptionKey` is a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ord` function (http://php.net/ord) and the `mb_strlen` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)

```
<?php
$var = $vstrEncryptionKey;

for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($var, 'ASCII'); $i++)
{
   echo ord($var[$i]);
}
?>
```

This is modified code from the answer given in [How do I get the byte values of a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591446/how-do-i-get-the-byte-values-of-a-string-in-php)