# charset encode same in utf8 but difference in ANSI

Tags: php, mysql

I have two text in utf-8, they should equal each other:

> Nguyễn Hoàn Vy - ĐĐ

and

> Nguyễn Hoàn Vy - ĐĐ

But when i change endcode in notepad++ to ANSI it show difference as below:

> NguyÃªÌƒn HoaÌ€n Vy - ÄÄ

> Nguyá»…n HoÃ n Vy - ÄÄ

It make problem when i process where like in the Mysql.

Comment: Check the byte values of those two UTF-8 strings, to see where they differ.

Comment: Can you let me know how to do it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22561567/4271923  dump value of `unpack('C*', $string)`.

Answer (score 0):

I run following query after connecting to database and all problems with utf-8 solve

```
"SET NAMES 'utf8'"
```

Comment: I already used it. The problem come from end user's data. I typing in the form then Nguyễn Hoàn Vy - ĐĐ (UTF-8) and NguyÃªÌƒn HoaÌ€n Vy - ÄÄ  in ANSI. 
But when user copy data from their excel then i have  Nguyễn Hoàn Vy - ĐĐ (UTF-8) and Nguyá»…n HoÃ n Vy - ÄÄ  in ANSI